# Speech Recognition (Python): How to resolve the "RequestError: Bad Request"?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, urllib, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

### My Problem

I am using the  [python speech recognition library by Uberi](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition) in order to transcribe a .wav audio file into plain text. However, when I run my code - using Google Speech Recognition - I get a RequestError.
For this (specific) error I found an [Opened Issue](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/482) on the speech recognition GitHub, yet without any answers.

How can I solve that issue? I know that I could try and use a different engine instead of Google; however it looks like they all require a Key and I had the hope of transcribing my file without one.

### My Code

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

clip = "MyFile.wav"

#Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)
r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Audio file as source
# listening the audio file and store in audio_text variable

with sr.AudioFile(clip) as source:
    audio_text = r.record(source)

text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
print(text)
```

### The Error

`speech_recognition.RequestError: recognition request failed: Bad Request`

[image: RequestError]

### An Idea

One possible reason might be the size of my .wav (~ 1 GB). I am going to try running my code later on with a small .wav to check that.

Answer (score 3):

Likely the size of audio file, also the length of document is too long to be processed.

Try this line to see if the text recognition works for the audio's first 4 seconds:
(if it works, it means yes - the whole file is too big)

```
with file_audio as source:
    audio_text = r.record(source, duration=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Bad Request response status code

The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

So this essentially means that it isn't Google's fault or your Uberi library's fault. It is on your end. You said that your .wav file is too large which is precisely what I think. These systems essentially take the audio file and break it down to be then recognized for text. You, as the client, were sending too large of a file. These systems can also time out at a certain point leading to the Error 400 as this is done through the internet as opposed to offline processing. The program you have is perfectly written and should do as intended with slightly smaller files.